# BGE Animated Fireball Group

Tags: animation, game-engine

In my game I have an Empty that adds my object magicfbgroup to the scene.

Magicfbgroup is a fireball I made by using several spheres with the same image texture that spin in different directions. It also has 3 planes for x,y,z in the middle that spin as well. All are at about .2 alpha to make a pretty cool fireball... I like it anyways.

I originally had an object that was made by joining several planes then using property to add/kill each plane. In the object I was using always + location to make the fireball shoot forward. This was working, but I like my new fireball wayyy better.

I couldn't make all of my spheres and planes a single object because it messes it up. Seems somethings happening in the difference between Group and Object. When I play the animation now it either goes in a pretty cool orbital loop that i may use later. As the objects are rotating in the animation they are then moving +1. So instead of spinning in place and shooting forward it goes into orbit. Or I can get it to play the animation once, then shoot forward, but the animation stops. Doing LoopStop causes the orbit.

I need the fireball to move forward and end if it collides.

I tried making a stationary sphere in the middle of my fireball and parenting the group objects to it. Still happening.

I think I have screwed up something with location/rotation some where or I need to lock the direction it can move some how and I'm just missing it.

Any ideas? This a dumb way to make a cool fire ball?

Answer (score 0):

## Groups within the BGE

Typically you do not work with groups as the BGE does not support groups.

The BGE supports group instances, but a bit differently than Blender.

An instance typically consists of

- the instance members (copies of the objects assigned to the group) and
- the dupli group objects (typically an empty)

While in Blender you can move the dupli group object around and the members will follow within the BGE they have no relationship. When you move the dupli group object the instance member will remain where they are.

I just tell you that to explain why I think your issue has nothing to do with groups.

## Orbiting animation

Orbiting usually occurs when you move an object forward along a local axis and rotate at a local axis. You basically change the direction of your forward move. In natural words: you move in a curve

Spinning is orbiting without moving.

But how to move along a path and still spin around yourself? You do not move forward at you local axis, but at another axis that is not local. Example: you do a step towards your target without caring your local orientation.

This can be hard as you need to compensate your local orientation.

What if you do not move at all? You let you move and just focus on orbiting.

A simple way is you parent the spinning object to another object (e.g. an empty). This way the spinning object does not move (relative to the parent). Then you can move the parent as you like. The motion will not influence the rotation and vice versa. Make sure you move the parent and turn the child.